# UI customizable Angularjs carousel module

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working to migrate my existing jquery based code into Angularjs. In my application I have existing code to implement carousel with different flavor and each carousel is very much customized in terms of UI,however current code has lot of duplicate code to support different variation therefore I don't like it. 
I was searching the carousel module in Angularjs which I can use as core module and customize it for my application however found many and therefore confused. I came across following.

```
1. angular-carousel http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-carousel
2. angular ui carousel module https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
3. angular-slick https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick
4. Wallop Slider in AngularJS http://andyshora.com/wallop-slider-angularjs-css.html
5. Based on Angularjs animation http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/
6. Angular.js and Bootstrap 3 http://www.cssscript.com/responsive-image-carousel-with-angular-js-and-bootstrap-3/
```

Following is summary of my requirement

```
1. Customize the UI, mainly on the location of "next" & "prev" button and slides
2. Support of single or multiple slides based on configuration
3. Infinite loop control based on configuration
4. Touch support on mobile and tablets
5. Responsive design, mainly for multiple slides control so that different number of slides can be display based on different screen size
```

Since I am getting multiple options therefore I am very much confused. Looking for help to to know which core Angular js based Carousel I can use so that I can customize it for various carousel module I have.

Comment: Without knowing much about any of the other options, the UI-bootstrap (option 2) carousel seems to fit your requirements perfectly. check out their [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tYY1IUiu0MpSe5iY0fcM?p=preview). btw, UI-bootstrap IS Angularjs + Bootstrap.

Comment: I am thinking to try angular-slick, as I need to have multiple items in one slide. I never tried any of these, therefore don't want to try all options. Will also try angularjs-ui.